# c++: constexpr function doesn't evaluate at compile time when using with std::cout

Tags: c++, c++14

I'm new with c++ and currently came across with `constexpr`. As I realize `constexpr` functions are evaluated at compile time. Here is my source code:

```
constexpr int sum(float a, int b)
{
    return a + b;
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    std::cout << sum(1, 2) << std::endl;
}
```

It is a simple function which just sums to integers. The problem is that when I set breakpoint at `return a + b` and start debugging, the breakpoint is hit, which means that the function was not evaluated at compile time. But when I change main function to this:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    constexpr int var = sum(2, 2);
    std::cout << var << std::endl;
}
```

the breakpoint is not hit, which means that function was evaluated at compile time. I'm little confused why function is not evaluated in first case?

**P.S**
I'm using visual studio 2017.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> As I realize constexpr functions are evaluated at compile time

Not really. They can be evaluated at compile-time, but they are not guaranteed to do so, unless they're invoked in a context where a *constant expression* is required.

One such context is the declaration of a `constexpr` variable.

Comment: I'm not sure if it is important, but `sum()` is defined `int(float,int)` and is invoked with `(ìnt,int)`; there are an implicit conversion (`int -> float`) in the call.

Comment: Worng, constexpr are guaranteed to be evaluated at compile time as long as the arguments are constexpr themselves. Only you don't get an error unless you require the result at compile time.

Comment: @NorbertLange uh, can you point to the Standard quote for that?

Comment: No I cant, as you are right and I am wrong (cant seem to undo my downvote for now).

Quote from the C++ Std:
Although in some contexts constant expressions must be evaluated during program translation, others
may be evaluated during program execution. Since this International Standard imposes no restrictions on the
accuracy of floating-point operations, it is unspecified whether the evaluation of a floating-point expression
during translation yields the same result as the evaluation of the same expression (or the same operations
on the same values) during program execution.

Comment: For the "guaranteed to do so" case, C++20 adds `consteval`.

Answer (score 9):

`constexpr` means "can be evaluated at compile time" rather than "must be evaluated at compile time". If you want to see it evaluated at compile time you can call it in a context that requires to be evaluated at compile time, for example a template parameter:

```
std::array<int, sum(3,5)> x;
```

Note that the motivation for `constexpr` is the other way around than many would expect. `constexpr` tells the compiler that you can use it eg as template parameter and if `sum` was not `constexpr` you'd get a compiler error. It is not to make sure that the function always is evaluated at compile time.